# Consistency Check - Ouput showing all false (Baseline)

Tags: python

Im trying to read this baseline and ensure that the input file consist of that value. As long as it consist of "x=1,y=2" it should be true. Now I am getting all false. Base on the input file im supposingly getting all OK instead of NOK.
This is my baseline:
[image]

This is my input file: [image]

Currently this is the output im getting : [image]

And here is my code:

```
cols_list = ['mecontext_id', 'managedelement_id']
cols_list.extend(process_conditional_cols(df1['paramter_condition'].tolist()))
cols_list.extend(process_conditional_cols(df1['target_parameter_value'].tolist()))
final_cols_list = process_conditional_cols(cols_list)
cols_list.extend(df1['target_parameter_value'].tolist())

nr_summary_data = pd.DataFrame()

condition_col = None  

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    filtered_rows = pd.DataFrame()

    conditions = row['paramter_condition'].split(',')
    target = row['target_parameter_value']
    baseline = row['baseline']

    condition_name = 'condition_' + row['paramter_condition'].replace(' ', '') + '_' + str(index)
    baseline_name = 'baseline_for_' + row['paramter_condition'].replace(' ', '') + '_' + str(index)

    print(f"Processing row {index} with conditions: {conditions}, target: {target}, baseline: {baseline}")

    param_value_pairs = [condition.split('=') for condition in conditions if '=' in condition]
    params = [pair[0].strip() for pair in param_value_pairs]
    values = []

    for pair in param_value_pairs:
        try:
            values.append(int(pair[1]))
        except ValueError:
            values.append(pair[1])

    mask = np.ones(len(df2), dtype=bool)
    df3mask = np.ones(len(df2), dtype=bool)

    params = []
    values = []

    condition_col = []

    for condition in conditions:
        print(f"df2[target] dtype: {df2[target].dtype}")
        print(f"baseline dtype: {type(baseline)}")

        if '=' in condition:
            param, value = condition.split('=')
            params.append(param.strip())
            values.append(value.strip())
        else:
            print(f"Checking condition1: {condition} for target: {target}, baseline: {baseline}")
            #condition_mask = (df2[condition.strip()] == baseline)
            condition_check = all(part in df2[condition_col] for part in baseline.split(','))
            mask &= condition_check



            #print(f"Condition Mask: {condition_mask.values}")
            print(f"Condition Check1: {condition_check}")

            #mask &= condition_mask & condition_check
            #mask &=  condition_check

    for param, value in zip(params, values):
        if isinstance(value, int):
            print(f"Checking {param} == {value} for target: {target}, baseline: {baseline}")
            value_mask = (df2[param] == value)
            value_check = all(value.strip() in df2[target] for value in baseline)
            print(f"Value Mask2: {value_mask.values}")
            print(f"Value Check2: {value_check}")

            df3mask |= value_mask & value_check
            mask &= value_mask & value_check
        else:
            print(f"Checking {param} == {value.strip()} for target: {target}, baseline: {baseline}")
            value_mask = (df2[param] == value.strip())
            value_check = all(value.strip() in df2[target] for value in baseline)
            print(f"Value Mask3: {value_mask.values}")
            print(f"Value Check3: {value_check}")

            df3mask &= value_mask & value_check
            mask &= value_mask & value_check



    filtered_rows = df2[df3mask]

    status = 'OK' if mask.all() else 'NOK'
    filtered_rows['parameter_condition'] = ', '.join(params)
    filtered_rows['parameter_condition_value'] = ', '.join(map(str, values))
    filtered_rows['parameter_used'] = ', '.join(f"{param}={value}" for param, value in zip(params, values))
    filtered_rows['baseline_value'] = f"{target}={baseline}"
    filtered_rows['target_parameter'] = target
    filtered_rows['target_value'] = df2.loc[df3mask, target].values
    filtered_rows['source_file'] = source_file
    #filtered_rows['status'] = 'OK' if any(baseline_part in df2[target].str.split(',') for baseline_part in baseline.split(',')) else 'NOK'
    filtered_rows['status'] = status



    nok_rows = filtered_rows[filtered_rows['status'] == 'NOK']

    df2.loc[nok_rows.index, 'cell_id'].values
    output_csv_filename = 'summary.csv'
    
    selected_columns = nok_rows[['source_file','parameter_condition', 'parameter_condition_value', 'parameter_used', 'baseline_value', 'target_parameter', 'target_value', 'status']]

    file_exists = os.path.exists(output_csv_filename)
    selected_columns.to_csv(output_csv_filename, mode='a', index=False, header=not file_exists)
```